# How to get Acknowlegement in TCP communication in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have written a socket program in Java. Both server and client can sent/receive data to each other. But I found that if client sends data to server using TCP then internally TCP sends acknowledgement to the client once the data is received by the server. I want to detect or handle that acknowledgement. How can I read or write data in TCP so that I can handle TCP acknowledgement.  Thanks.

Comment: Please consider removing references to TCP and talk about application level behavior only.  The client sends a request to the server which receives it.  The server sends a message *from the application* back to the client as a response but the client never receives the response.  Is that what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 7):

This is simply not possible, even if you were programming in C directly against the native OS sockets API.  One of the points of the sockets API is that it abstracts this away for you.

The sending and receiving of data at the TCP layer doesn't necessarily correlate with your Java calls to send or receive data.  The data you send in one Java call may be broken into several pieces which may be buffered, sent and received independently, or even received out of order.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173153/when-does-a-java-socket-send-an-ack) for more discussion about this.

Answer (score 2):

Any data sent over a TCP socket is acknowledged in both directions.  Data sent from client to server is the same as data sent from server to client as far as TCP wire communications and application signaling.  As @Eric mentions, there is no way to get at that signaling.

It may be that you are talking about timing out while waiting for the response from the server.  That you'd like to detect if a response is taking too long.  Is it possible that the client's message is larger than the server's response so the buffering is getting in the way of the response but not the initial request?  Have you tried to use non-blocking sockets?

You might want to take a look at the [NIO code](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html) if you have not already done so.  It has a number of classes that give you more fine grained control over socket communications.

Comment: Incorrect, see my answer, and NIO doesn't help in this matter in the slightest.

Comment: I'm sorry, how is it incorrect?  What is the difference between a byte sent from the client to the server versus from server to client?

I suspect that the question is confusing TCP sockets with (as you allude to) buffering and other issues which is the reason I mention non-blocking and NIO.

Comment: It's incorrect because it doesn't answer the question. He wants to 'detect or handle that acknowledgement' and there is nothing in this answer that address that.

Comment: Wow.  A 2 year old thread.  You're obviously backed up @EJP.  :-)  I agree that the answer is subpar.  I'll tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in pure Java since Java's network API all handles socket, which hides all the TCP details.

You need a protocol that can handle IP-layer data so you can get TCP headers. DLPI is the most popular API to do this,

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9638599/chap1.htm

Unfortunately, there is not Java implementation of such network. You have to use native code through JNI to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to detect or handle that acknowledgement.

There is no API for receiving or detecting the ACKs at any level above the protocol stack.

Rethink your requirement. Knowing that the data has got to the server isn't any use to an application. What you want to know is that the peer *application* has received it, in which case you have to get the peer application to acknowledge at the application protocol level.

Comment: "TCP/IP practices 'selective ACK'. Not every byte/packet/segment is acknowledged."  As I read it, this is incorrect.  SACK is about informing the sender that packets ahead of missing packets have been received so only the missing packets need to be retransmitted.  If a packet arrives on the receiver, it _will_ be acknowledged -- either in a specific ack or as part of a cumulative ack.

Comment: Agreed, amending. Remainder of my answer still applies.

Comment: You didn't @Gray me in your response so I hadn't come back to see that you significantly edited your post to remove incorrect information.   Downvote removed.  I expect all of your 1740 downvotes were commented on EJP?  :-)

Comment: @Gray If you mean my downvotes of other questions or answers, yes, unless I upvoted an existing comment instead, or perhaps voted to close. Thanks for your message.