# How do Java TCP/IP sockets report transmission success or failure to the application?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am having a problem with Java TCP/IP sockets: my Java application will continue endlessly to send data to a server even if the server gets switched off (without a proper TCP/IP disconnect) in the meantime.

I am using the following code to send the data:

```
PrintWriter out = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.write("text");

if (out.checkError()) {
   System.err.println("Error sending string!");
}
```

In [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173153/when-does-a-java-socket-send-an-ack/2173194#2173194), I found the following answer:

> TCP/IP (and therefor java sockets)
>   will guarantee that you either
>   successfully send the data OR get an
>   error (exception in the case of java)
>   eventually.

Is my code sufficient for getting informed about the TCP/IP stack not being able to successfully send my string or do I need to do something additionally?

Btw: was it correct to open a new question even though the other question was similar? It did not answer my question satisfactorily and I was only able to add a new answer, not a new comment.

Comment: First think I liked about you is... your name TAJMAHAL :). Secondly, you can ask as many questions as you want as its free and open. _But you should not._ If you find a similar question try to find a solution out of it for your version. If anyways its not possible, do it like you did. Refer to other question what you already saw, put in here what all you tried and the place where you think you are stuck. Stackoverflow guy's are awesome if you have a genuine/good question. Otherwise your question may be closed/moved/downvoted etc etc. I sufferred all that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I didn't mention (as I thought it was not relevant at that time) is that I am trying to do this on Android.

After several weeks of testing, though, it seems that Android's implementation of the standard Java networking classes is behaving very differently from the Oracle JRE. On Android, it is apparently impossible to reliably detect if the connection has been closed, even if I closed it myself. `[Stream].write()` will try writing for several minutes. So on Android, it appears that you will always need to send your own keep-alives (and check for reception!) for detecting a broken connection.

The other answers to this question will work fine with the Oracle JRE. Thanks again!

If anyone can provide further information on this topic, please do so.

Comment: I agree, sockets on Android are buggy, they often don’t raise any exception when they should.

Answer (score 4):

You might have two problems: `PrintWriter` is a strange beast in the Java `Stream`/`Reader`/`Writer` world in that it swallows exceptions and requires you to explicitly check for errors.

The only use for this (in my opinion) are the standard streams (`System.out` and `System.err`), where failure to write output should not halt the application (for example if no standard output is available).

Replace that with an `OutputStreamWriter` and you'll be informed about errors as soon as Java knows about them.

That brings me to the second possible problem: TCP/IP doesn't have any automated keep-alive packets: so *if* your connection gets severed in some way, you won't actually notice it until you attempt to send data.

So if you connect to some socket, send some packets, wait a bit and *then* get disconnected, you will only be notified of the fact when you next try to send some data. This is inherent in the TCP/IP protocol and not the fault of Java.

If you want to reduce the problem, then you could send periodic keep-alive/ping messages with no actual effect, except that they check if the connection is still alive.

Comment: But if I unplug the network cable to the server and keep sending a message every second, how long should it take `out.checkError()` to find out that transmission was unsuccessful? Seconds? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: I replaced the PrintWriter with an OutputStreamWriter but I can still unplug the network cable and transmit for ages without getting an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is different enough I'd say. Google has a lot to say about this sort of thing though. The keep-alives (`SO_KEEPALIVE`) are not designed for this sort of thing. From what I have read the TCP spec says that they should *not* be sent more than once every two hours and it is up to your OS to manage it so you don't have much control. I emphasize *from what I have read*.

Whether you can use them more than once every two hours doesn't matter in your case though since you are continually sending data. Keep-alives are only needed if you want to detect a broken connection while you are not sending data.

If you were using the `OutputStream` of the `Socket` directly, it would throw an exception when you attempt to send to an unavailable destination (for whatever reason that may be). Since you are using `PrintWriter`, you need to check for errors manually using `checkError()`.

So, in summary: Yes, it is sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: So why is it not working for me? I can unplug the cable to the server and keep sending data to it for _minutes_ without getting an error. I am currently sending a message every second. Shouldn't the TCP/IP stack notice the missing ACKS and notify the application layer?

Comment: Yes, it should. Try using the `OutputStream` directly and see if that improves things for you: `socket.getOutputStream().write("text".toBytes());`. It should throw an exception. Or use the class @Joachim suggested. Had I seen his answer I probably wouldn't have bothered writing mine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even though the server has died, your client application is not informed about it.  Usually this is a bad router somewhere failing to shut down both sides of the connection.  You should set up [keep-alives](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_KEEPALIVE) so you can detect this kind of failure.

Depending on your OS there are ways to change the keep-alive test interval.

Answer (score 0):

One special condition applies when you are closing the socket. Depending on the socket opt `SO_LINGER` (see this [article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/socketOpt.html)) you set, the `close()` call will either return immediately or wait until all pending TCP transmissions were either  successful or an error occured, which is then signalled by an IOException thrown from the `close()` implementation.

Also `SO_TIMEOUT`has an effect on when retries will time out.